# Is there a way to do an automated build of an open-source project on Google Code?

Tags: c#, open-source, build, build-automation

I have an open-source C# project on Google Code Project Hosting and I'm curious if there is a service that does automated daily builds of projects hosted there. It would be great if it it would do builds regularly and then provide binaries to download, or at least notify if the project fails to build.

Does anything like that exist? Also, if there are none for Google Code, does this exist for another project hosting service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[teamcity.codebetter.com](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/) provides continuous integration (with TeamCity) for open source projects, no matter where the code is hosted.
You can read more about it (including how to apply your project) [here](http://codebetter.com/codebetter-ci/).

---

**EDIT:**

I see your point, but's it's the only free CI offer for open source projects that I know of. And it's a generous offer - CodeBetter is no company, but a group of individual bloggers. So I guess they have to pay for server capacity themselves.
The TeamCity Enterprise Edition is sponsored by JetBrains (makers of TeamCity).
I just noticed that [you can get the Enterprise Edition for free directly from JetBrains when you're an open source project](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/buy.jsp#openSource), but you have to apply for that as well.
But then you just get the software itself...no hosting, you would need to take care of that yourself.

But I think the fact that you have to apply for it (either way) is not that bad.
Sure, it would be nicer if you could just register and that's it, but think about it...you get software [worth $1999 (plus $999 yearly renewal!)](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/index.jsp) completely for free, all you need to do is apply for it.

Comment: This seems awesome but thoroughly confuses me. lol. I also don't like how you have to email them and "hope" they do it for you, but +1 for the link.

Comment: I edited my answer, see above!

Answer (score 2):

There start-up project called [AppHarbour](https://appharbor.com/)

It clams, that it can build and publish you web site, using only Git/Mercurial-push operation.
I haven't tried it but the idea seems promising.

EDIT: This service provides automated-deployment to it's own cloud, so it is not suitable solely for CI testing, but is still interesting if you use it, as a cloud service provider.